# Get a count of active AWS network interfaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I need to get a count of the number of 'active' network interfaces in my region.

I can use the query below to list out the active interfaces, however I am uncertain on how to get a 'count' of the active interfaces and not just a json payload as the output.

I can run this cli command to get the list of all attached interfaces.

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters "Name=group-name,Values=Redis" "Name=attachment.status,Values=attached"
```

However I'm not sure how to get a count of interfaces that are attached, i tried the query below but I'm not getting the desired output to just get a count.

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters "Name=group-name,Values=Redis" "Name=attachment.status,Values=attached" --query 'NetworkInterfaces[*][Attachment.Status,Attachment.Status.Count]'
```

The output comes out like below.

```
[
    [
        "attached",
        null
    ],
    [
        "attached",
        null
    ],
    [
        "attached",
        null
    ],
    [
        "attached",
        null
    ]
]
```

What I'd like to see if something like below.

```
[
  [
     type: "attached",
     Count: "x"
  ]
]
```

Comment: What do you consider an "active" ENI? Merely something that is connected to an instance? An instance that is running? Or with actual traffic within the last _x_ hours? Can you tell us _why_ you want to obtain this count (we might be able to offer an alternative idea)?

Comment: We had an issue recently where we exhausted our number of ENI's (value was set to 350).  We've since increased our allocation of ENI's for our account, but I would like to monitor the number of ENI's that are active so if we reach a certain threshold we are notified so we can investigate, before it causes a production outage.

Comment: Okay, so if you're just worried about that limit, it would be a count of all ENIs in the region, regardless of whether they are attached to something.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to count the number of Elastic Network Interfaces (ENIs) in the region to know when you are approaching the limit.

The limits page in the EC2 management console doesn't seem to state that the ENI count is only for *attached* images, so you should probably count the total number of ENIs.

This could be done with:

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --query 'length(NetworkInterfaces)'
```

If you only wish to count count ENIs that are `attached`, use:

```
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces --filters Name=attachment.status,Values=attached --query 'length(NetworkInterfaces)'
```